# Linear differential equation of the second order with a regular singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the general solution of the equation $\frac{d^{2} y}{dx^{2} } =\frac{1}{x} y$, please? Thank you in advance.

I'm interested in a more general question. Assume that there exists a **single-valued** solution to the equation $f'(z)+f^{2} (z)=\frac{1}{z} +b(z)$, where $b(z)$ is a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of zero . It is clear that $f(z)=\frac{w'}{w} $, where $w$ is the solution of the equation $w''=\left(\frac{1}{z} +b(z)\right )w$. Is it possible to show that $f(z)=\frac{w'}{w} =\frac{1}{z} +a_{0} +a_{1} z+a_{2} z^{2} +...$ ? Thanks to the help of Kurt G. and Nasser, in the case of $b(z)\equiv 0$ this seems possible, because the power series of the function $K_{1} (z)$ contains $\log z$, which is not holomorphic in the ring $0<\left|z\right|<\delta $. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: There is a general theory of such equations in the book

W. Wazov, "Asymptotic expansions for ordinary differential equations", Interscience (1965), equation (5.32).

But maybe someone has a ready answer?

Comment: Or Wolfgang Wasow  "Asymptotic expansions for ordinary differential equations", Dover Pubns (1987), equation (5.32).

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27+-+y%2Fx+%3D+0) finds the following solution
$$
y(x)=c_1\sqrt{x}I_1(2\sqrt{x})+c_2\sqrt{x}K_1(2\sqrt{x})
$$
where $I_n,K_n$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind.

I leave my previous attempt below. It was pointed out by Lutz Lehmann
that it is wrong essentially because the matrices $A(x)$ and $A(y)$ do
not commute.

***Previous Attempt***

The 2nd order differential equation
$$
y''=\frac{y}{x}
$$
is equivalent to the system of 1st order ODEs
\begin{cases}
y_1'=y_2\,,\\[2mm]
y_2'=\frac{y_1}{x}\,.
\end{cases}
In matrix-vector form we can write this as
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\mathbf{y}'=A(x)\,\mathbf{y}\,,\quad A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\frac{1}{x}&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align}

***So far so good. This is where it gets wrong.***

The general solution of (1) is [***wrong***]
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\mathbf{y}(x)=\color{red}{\exp\Big(\int_{x_0}^xA(u)\,du\Big)}\,\mathbf{y}(x_0)
\end{align}
where $x_0\not=0$ and a matrix exponential is used. The integral of the matrix $A(x)$ can be
written as
\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^xA(u)\,du=\begin{pmatrix}0&x-x_0\\\log(x/x_0)&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align}

To see why (2) is wrong, note that the Euler discretization of (1) gives
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}(x_i)&\approx \mathbf{y}(x_{i-1})+A(x_{i-1})\,\Delta x\,\mathbf{y}(x_{i-1})=\big(I+A(x_{i-1})\,\Delta x\,\big)\,\mathbf{y}(x_{i-1})\\[2mm]
&\approx e^{A(x_{i-1})\Delta x}\,\mathbf{y}(x_{i-1})\,.
\end{align}
The iteration of this gives
$$
\mathbf{y}(x_n)\approx\prod_{i=1}^n e^{A(x_{i-1})\Delta x}\,\mathbf{y}(x_0).
$$
***Only when all matrices $A(x_{i-1})$ commute*** we can write this product as
$$
\exp\Big(\sum_{i=1}^nA(x_{i-1})\Delta x\Big).
$$
Surely, in the limit $\Delta x\to 0$ the sum gives the integral $\int_0^{x_n}A(u)\,du$ - however we have not reached this point of salvation.

Comment: This is wrong, it only applies to constant matrices and some very special cases of non-constant system matrices.

Comment: @LutzLehmann . Keen to learn something. It is not true that (2) solves (1) ?

Comment: No. The factors have the wrong order and the propagator is only the integral if all matrices $A(x)$ commute.

Comment: Makes double sense. Thanks ! I will delete the answer tomorrow. Meanwhile I think that even from a wrong answer one can learn how it cannot be done.